# Inconsistent ToggleButton behaviour inside huge ExpandableListview

Tags: android, togglebutton

I have a expandable list with a toggleable favourite button in each row. The list is huge, with 1000+ elements. When one of the elements is toggled and the list starts scrolling, buttons are activated and deactivated at seemingly random places.

I have the suspect it may be due to memory behaviour when trying to reach my views, where the indexes are similar for the current in-memory list.

Element:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/fav"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:background="@drawable/fav_toggle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the fav_toggle state control is as simple as

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off" />
</selector>
```

The button is not retrieved or used inside the code, checked and doublechecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view that contained the button is being reused by Android's OS to build newer views. As the button state is not stored and rechecked when the view is rebuilt in the Adapter, it retains the one from the previous view. If that view had the button checked, it will keep the same state.